# Geokit Rails: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geokit

I'm getting an error that happens for one model and not the other. I can run `Job.all.within(5, :origin => [0, 0])`, but not `User.all.within(5, :origin => [0, 0])`, even though they have the same info in their models: `acts_as_mappable lng_column_name: :longitude, lat_column_name: :latitude`

For the broken case, it seems to be breaking here (this is code from the Geokit gem):

```
 def within(distance, options = {})
    options[:within] = distance
    #geo_scope(options)
    where(distance_conditions(options))  # HERE
  end
```

Where, if I interrupt, I can output:

```
>> options
=> {:within=>5}
>> distance_conditions(options)
!! #<TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer>
```

What's going on?

Comment: Immediately found the line in my files that brakes it. I was also using the Geocoder gem. The line `geocoded_by :postcode` in my `Job` model was breaking it. I can probably take the Geocoder gem out if I'm using geokit.

Comment: Ok, so the fix turns out to be: You need "acts_as_mappable" to be after "geocoded_by" in your model.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer and accept it please, I almost didn't see the comment and it solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

There seems a dependency issue with `geocoder` gem. Removing `geocoder` gem should work

```
 Location.within(5, :origin => [37.792,-122.393])
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me turned out to be: You need "acts_as_mappable" to be after "geocoded_by" in your model.